# Ошибка при подключении к серверу Exim4 через netcat

Tags: email, putty, exim, linux

В общем, проблема такая: с целью повышения опыта поставил себе на Debian MTA exim. При тестировании отправил письмо с этой же машины - оно нормально отложилось в папке inbox. Дальше решил подключиться в ручном режиме:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 25.
```

Пишет ошибку:

> Connection refused.

Через putty то же самое. Поясните, что не так? Только сильно не ругайте: я просто новичок в этом деле.

**Проблема решена переустановкой exim**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так и в чём вопрос? Порт 25 либо закрыт, либо... порт 25 всё-таки закрыт.

Comment: Подскажите, будьте другом, как просмотреть тут, какие порты открыты, и соответственно открыть 25? iptables посмотрел - но это либо не то, либо я не очень разобрался.

Comment: Зачем вы вообще пытаетесь подключиться к почтовому SMTP-серверу напрямую? Что вы думаете ему сообщить вручную через SMTP-протокол (пусть и текстовый)? iptables по идее не должен рубить ничего через loopback, так что маловероятно, что он виноват. Я бы сказал, что ваш SMTP-сервер либо остановлен, либо работает через какой-то другой порт..

Comment: Конечная цель - написание клиента для отправки почты (простенького, в целях изучения протокола), поэтому сначала нужно проверить работоспособность сервера, что не очень выходит. При этом сервер точно запущен и порт по умолчанию 25. Проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: Чудес ведь не бывает, верно? Либо вы подключаетесь не к той машине, либо сервер остановлен, либо порт не тот. У меня вот запущен и всё работает. Скорее всего вы делаете что-то не то..

Comment: Ну, а как проверить открыт он или нет? И если закрыт, то как открыть? Просто я не особо разбираюсь в файерволах на Linux. Отвечаете на вопрос и я сразу ставлю отмечаю ответ как зачтённый.

Comment: Файерволы обычно не проверяют loopback (вы ведь сами к себе подключаетесь). Но если очень хочется проверить именно это, то можете сбросить все цепочки (iptables -F) и проверить, есть ли коннект. Либо проверить вручную цепочки через iptables -L.

Comment: man netstat

Answer (score 0):

Если при подключении putty повисает, то, скорее всего, неверен адрес подключения или он недоступен. Если ошибка появляется практически сразу, посмотрите, установлен ли у вас openssh-server openssh-client, правда, это смотрится, если вы через ssh идете. Если вы используете другой протокол, смотрите дополнительные библиотеки для него.

Comment: 25й порт обслуживается SMTP-сервером, а не ssh

Comment: Верно, ssh тут не причём.